# Проблемы с компиляцией

Tags: qt, qt5

Есть класс

```
class LoaderToTextEdit : public QObject, public ILoader  {

Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit LoaderToTextEdit(QTextEdit & ATextEdit, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

LoaderToTextEdit(const LoaderToTextEdit & ALogger);

const LoaderToTextEdit & operator =(const LoaderToTextEdit & ALogger);

virtual ~LoaderToTextEdit();

virtual void sendMessage(ILoader::MessageType AMesgType,const QString & AMessage);

private slots:
void onTimer();

private:

QMutex          * FMutex;
QTextEdit       * FTextEdit;
QQueue<QString> * FLoggerQueue;
QTimer          * FLoggerTimer;

void initTimer();
};
```

Реализации конструкторов и деструкторов в cpp есть. При компиляции ошибка:

> undefined reference to `vtable for LoaderToTextEdit'

на конструкторах и деструкторе.

Помогите разобраться!

Comment: а у sendMessage там есть реализация?

Comment: А конструктор и деструктор определен?

Comment: реализация есть у всех методов, конструкторов и деструкторов

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Ошибка «undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'» в классе с Q_OBJECT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796894/208074)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта проблема имеет два возможных корня:

1) Не реализована какая-то из функций, объявленных как слот. В Qt слоты должны иметь реализацию.

2) Отсутствуют moc файлы из-за того, что не отработал qmake после добавления макроса `Q_OBJECT`

В первом случае ищем, какой из слотов не имеет реализации и добавляем ее (как верно пишут в комментариях, надо также проверить конструктор и деструктор)

Во втором случае вручную запускаем qmake (в QtCreator в меню Build - Run qmake) и пересобираем проект

Comment: второй случай отработал. все собралось